# Does every finite poset have a rigid endomorphism?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, order-theory

[Crossposted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/373829/461) on MathOverflow.

In this post, an order-preserving self-map of a poset $X$ will be called an **endomorphism** of $X$, and such an endomorphism $f$ will be called **rigid** if the only automorphism of $X$ which commutes with $f$ is the identity of $X$.

The question is in the title:

> Does every finite poset have a rigid endomorphism?

Every poset of cardinality at most $9$ has a rigid endomorphism.

I wrote a proof of this statement in a separate text. Since links tend to break over time I am including several links to this text:

[pdf file](http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/%7EPierre-Yves.Gaillard/Rigid_endo_poset_mo/repmo.pdf) --- [tex  file](http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/%7EPierre-Yves.Gaillard/Rigid_endo_poset_mo/repmo.tex) --- [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/tczwvzwyqgjc) --- [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RP1v4kbIZ4iMo0xSjybcgeKtBRVnRcsd?usp=sharing) --- [Mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/3dityd6zt35rd/Rigid_endo_poset_mo).

In the first version of this question I put the proof in the post itself. But I realized that there was a mistake, and that the post was too long. So I rewrote the proof (hoping that it is correct now), and added links to the new version.